# In Shiism, what is the source of Imams' supreme knowledge?

Tags: shiism, islamic-philosophy, imamah

Shiites believe that their [Twelve Imams] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Imams), the rightful successors of the prophet, have complete knowledge of everything.

The question is: what are the origins of their knowledge? In other words, where do they get their knowledge from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some hadiths explained the sources of Imams knowledge in [Basair al Darajat book](http://www.followislam.net/ar/books/ahlulbait/basaer-aldarajat/) as follow:

> مبلغ علمنا على ثلاثة وجوه: ماض و غابر و حادث. فاما الماض فمفسر و اما
>   الغابر فمزبور و اما الحادث فقذف فى القلوب و نقر فى الاسماع و هو افضل
>   علمنا و لا نبى بعد نبينا
>
> our knowlegde sources are three faces: first,what occurred.second,what
>   is ocurring and third,what will occur.  first, [what ocurred] are
>   teachings of the prophet which give us  down from [Ali Ibn
>   Abi-talab].second [what is ocurring ]which are wriiten in[ fatima
>   book(sahifeh)]. third [what will occur] throwing in our heart [elham
>   ]or whispering in our ears  and this is our best knowlegde and there
>   is no messenger after our holy prophet mohammad peace be upon him.

First: the prophet taught Imam Ali his knowledge and called him as the Gate of his knowledge as [[following  hadiths]](http://www.al-milani.com/library/lib-pg.php?booid=19&mid=224&pgid=2472).this knowledge transferred to next Imams  :

> علمني رسول الله الف باب من العلم ، يفتح من كل باب الف باب
>
> Imam Ali (s) said: “The Prophet, in his deathbed, whispered to me and
>   taught me one thousand chapters of knowledge; each one of them
>   contained one thousand chapters.”

Or

> > قال رسول الله صلّى الله عليه وآله وسلّم: «أنا مدينة العلم وعلي بابها 
> >     فمن أراد العلم فليأت الباب
>
> "I am the city of knowledge and Ali is its gate..."

This knowledge transferred to next Imams also the Quran which collected by Imam Ali.

Second, interpretates to [moshaf of Fatima](http://askaralmahdi.com/Easm/q&a/mq9.html) (which sent down by Gabriel about some matters and facts written by Imam Ali ) or community or Jafar books.

Third, imams know about everything when ask him by throwing or whispering at the end stated that these [throwing or whispering] are not only for messengers.

Answer (score -3):

We also believe that the Prophet had that knowledge too, where did he get it?

The answer is: Allah taught the Prophet what he has. When the Prophet was going to die he gave Ali (a.s), his successor, his knowledge where he says:

> علمني رسول الله الف باب من العلم ، يفتح من كل باب الف باب
>
> Verily, the Holy Prophet taught me 1,000 chapters of knowledge, each chapter of which opened another 1,000 chapters

And that's it, every Imam transferred knowledge to his successor.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could cite sources for the hadith you quoted.